# Using quotes with "${parameter:-word}" Parameter Expansion

Tags: bash, shell, quotes, variable-expansion

When using the `${parameter:-word}` form of parameter expansion to evaluate to a default value if the variable is unset, what is the best practice for quotes?

For example, assume a Bash shell script with `-u` set (to generate an error when an undefined or unset variable is evaluated), to test if a variable has a value, what would be the best way to write the equivalent of `if [[ -z "$FOO" ]]`?

```
if [[ -z "${FOO:-}" ]]
```

or

```
if [[ -z ${FOO:-""} ]]
```

or something else?

Comment: Something else: `[[ -z ${FOO:-} ]]`

Comment: If you have Bourne Shell compatibility in mind, you may prefer `[ -z "${FOO:-}" ]` with a single-bracket test and double-quotes around the variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of `bash` (4.2 as of this writing), you can use the `-v` option to test if a variable is set without trying to expand it at all.

```
if [[ -v FOO ]]; then
    echo "FOO=$FOO"
else
    echo "FOO not set"
fi
```

If you are using an older version, I would just use

```
if [[ -z ${FOO:-} ]];
```

The quotes aren't necessary, and IMO this looks cleanest.

Comment: +1; specifically, the `-v` operator was introduced in `4.2` - see http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS. Older versions: `-z ${FOO:-}` is the _most robust form_ that works in _all_ situations; however, if bash was NOT started with `-u` or `set -u` (`set -o nounset`) was executed, `[[ -z $FOO ]]` works, too.

Comment: You don't need the `:` either.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it like this

```sh
if (( ! ${#FOO} ))
```

[Example](http://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/blob/3d0f4a0/apt-cyg#L345)

Comment: This will croak if `FOO` is unset (the OP mentions `set -u`).